# LWP::UserAgent returns incomplete 2GB response message

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am using `LWP::UserAgent`to send request on a URL. But sometime in the response I am getting incomplete `XML` response.

**Code**

```
$args->{pua} = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$args->{header} = HTTP::Headers->new;
$args->{header}->header("Content-Type" => "text/xml", "SOAPAction" => $args->{soapaction});
$request = HTTP::Request->new( "POST", $args->{endpoint}, $args->{header}, $args->{xml});
$response = $args->{pua}->simple_request($request);
my $xmlResponse = $response->content;
```

In the `$xmlResponse` sometime I am getting incomplete response. Why is it happening?

**ResponseHeader**

```
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 11:07:37 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Client-Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 11:07:40 GMT
Client-Peer: 202.77.98.11:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Please show the result of `print $xmlResponse->headers->as_string`

Comment: @Borodin response is very much long near about 2-3 gb i can't post that

Comment: Have you tried it? It will be only a dozen or so lines. However, expecting a 2GB HTTP message to arrive intact is a bit hopeful, and is probably the source of your problem. Are you asking for an entire database dump or something?

Comment: I would guess that the size of the message is the problem. A 32-bit signed value can hold up to 2,147,483,647 and so can represent the length of up to 2GB data. But please post the message headers as I asked

Comment: Do you have at least 4 GB free memory when you run this script? Does it work reliably if you save to a file instead of trying to hold a 2-3GB string in memory?

Comment: @Borodin i have updated the response header

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit Perl? Please show the output of `perl -v` if you're not sure

Comment: More accurately, `perl -V:ivsize`

Answer (score 1):

LWP may return incomplete response when it failed to read whole body because of the timeout or other read error. In this case `$response->is_success` will be `true` and `$response->code` will be `200`, but response headers will contain special header called `X-Died`.
So you can check this header:

```
unless ($response->is_success) {
    die "Response failed: ", $response->status_line;
}

if ($response->header('X-Died')) {
    die "Response failed (internal): ", $response->header('X-Died');
}
```

Comment: I am getting the response within the timeout limit.I have handled the response for error .But i want to get the response

Comment: This may be also some other read error, not only timeout. Anyway, try to check X-Died header.